# Disabling input devices from a Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, input, module, kernel, driver

I am writing a kernel module for detecting the tablet mode from a [2-in-1 laptop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-in-1_PC).

The module is accessing industrial I/O (or sensors) and needs to disable input devices (ex: internal keyboard and mouse). I would like doing it in kernel space to early disable the inputs (or the devices itself) if the laptop is powered on in tablet mode, avoiding users removing the splash screen at startup (for instance). Until now I have not found a way to disable the inputs without modifying the kernel sources.

**1st idea:**

Without modifying the kernel source,
my first attempt was to call the following function from `linux/input.h`, which "disables" a given input by ignoring its events:

```
    void input_set_ignore_events(struct input_dev *dev, bool ignored)
```

I have found a way to get a `struct device *` device with its name as following, but I cannot find a way to get a `struct input_dev *` pointer from `struct device *`:

```
    bus_find_device_by_name(&platform_bus_type, NULL, name);
```

Another idea would be to externaly access the `static LIST_HEAD(input_dev_list);` located into `drivers/input/input.c`.

**2nd idea:**

Do not try to access the kernel input abstraction but instead leverage `offline()` and `suspend()` functions of `struct bus_type *` from `include/linux/device.h`. According to the `Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-devices-online` it might work. I will try it soon.

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to disable properly events or inputs from any external module ?
- Is it possible to retrieve to a `struct input_dev *` from any external module ?

Thanks for your time.